# how to clean non used keywords

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 3 tables : "topics" and "keywords" and "topic_keyword" (relation table between Topics and keywords).

---

### Topics

+ID_topic (PK)

-name

-category

### Keywords

+ID_keyword (PK)

-name

### topic_keyword

+ID_Keyword (PK)

+ID_topic   (PK)

---

how to remove/clean not used rows in "topic_keyword"  ?

how to remove/clean not used rows in "keywords" ?

Comment: How can there be a not used row in topic_keyword. Topics with no keywords, and keywords with no topics I could understand

Comment: With 2 `DELETE` statements I imagine. Or a foreign key cascade in case of the `topic_keyword` table. What have you tried?

Comment: - I need to clean "keywords" table I mean remove rows from this table (keywords table) where keywords not used in "topic_keywords" table.

Comment: - and I need to remove rows from "topic_keywords" table where ID_topic doesn't exist in "posts" table

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, so like

```
    DELETE FROM Keywords k
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM topic_keyword tk where tk.id_keyword = k.id_keyword 
    );
```

Or similar if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: and I need to remove rows from "topic_keywords" table where ID_topic doesn't exist in "posts" table

Comment: It's the exact same pattern, just switch around the tables and column names to fit.